# Extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\cos(\theta)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\cos(\theta))$. I want to run this by someone but I am sure it's most likely true:

$\mathrm{Gal}(K / \mathbb{Q})$ is abelian $\Leftrightarrow$ $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a number $\theta$, not a rational multiple of $\pi$, such that $\cos\theta=1/3$, so the two properties are not equuivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have $\theta/\pi\in\Bbb Q$ implies $K=\Bbb Q(\cos\theta)$ is Abelian over $\Bbb Q$, but the converse is very far from being true.

For a start, $2\cos\theta$ is an algebraic integer
whenever $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$, so take any element of your
field that is real and lies between $-1$ and $1$ and which isn't half an algebraic
integer. Then we can write it as $\cos\theta$ and then $\theta\notin\Bbb Q\pi$.
As an example, you could always take $\theta=\cos^{-1}(1/3)$.